# adding event to another class after completion of a method

Tags: c#, events, reflection, delegates

Suppose I have two classes - one that is provided to me (but suppose I am not allowed to change it as it is maintained by someone else), and one that I control and can change.

```
// Class A is provided to me by someone else, and suppose I can't modify it
public class A
{
   public A()
   {
    ...
   }

   public void DoSomethingInA()
   {
    ...
   }
}

// Class B is what I control
public class B
{
   public A MyClassAInstance;

   public B(A myClassAInstance)
   {
     MyClassAInstance = myClassAInstance;

     // *** HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
     // NEED TO WRITE AN EVENT / EVENT HANDLER, WITH / WITHOUT REFLECTION
     // THAT RUNS DoSomethingInB WHENEVER MyClassAInstance's DoSomethingInA
     // METHOD IS CALLED (AND COMPLETED)
   }

   public void DoSomethingInB()
   {
    ...
   }

}
```

How can I define a Event / EventHandler in `class B` that kicks off its `DoSomethingInB` method whenever the `class A` instance `MyClassAInstance`'s method `DoSomethingInA` is called (and completed).

I tried lot of options, but none seem to work.

For instance, I tried:

```
public class B
{
   public A MyClassAInstance;

   public B(A myClassAInstance)
   {
     MyClassAInstance = myClassAInstance;

     var eventInfo = GetType().GetEvent("MyEvent");
     var methodInfo = myClassAInstance.GetType().GetMethod("DoSomethingInA");
     Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, myClassAInstance, methodInfo);
     eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, handler);
     MyEvent += DoSomethingInB;

   }

   public event EventHandler MyEvent;

   public void DoSomethingInB()
   {
    ...
   }

}
```

But this doesn't work.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might not be able to change the class, but why can't you inherit from it and add your own code as you then require?

Comment: class A is very heavy in computations and data (an entire engine etc. to do something) and already run in an application. class B is like a light weight e.g. for reporting. even if I inherit class A, there are actual instances (implementations) of many instances class A live in production (live running apps) that I can't change or can't get others to change just for the purpose of class B functionality. i am hoping that there is a work around.

Comment: i am looking if there is way to capture any method leaving (or method ending) event at a system level (may be in some system library that has that functionality)

Comment: If the code that's calling this function is all your code that you can update, then what about writing an extension method for class A that calls theDoSomethingInA function then fires off an event that this method has been called?

Comment: no, unfortunately, the DoSomethingInA method is called elsewhere and not under my control.

Comment: would either of you know if any thing like Process.Exited can be used for this?

Comment: Have you tried talking to the other devs about making an update to class A?

Comment: yes, but its a separate team which is not accommodating. office politics about control (i.e. power). i have no choice but to build around it.

Comment: Try doing some research into PostSharp: https://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator
It does require you to add attributes to methods to track them, so you might have to make a new class which inherits from class A or is a wrapper for class A. Afterwards then tell your boss that if the other devs don't use this new class, then it's their fault things haven't worked properly since they were too wingey to update class A and be team players.

Comment: @KingOfArrows, wow ! that's actually interesting. I am wondering if  I can add a decorator to the instance of class A in my class B and achieve that

Comment: You might want to check if updating an instance of ClassA will mean that all current and future instances of ClassA will incorporate your updates. Especially those that you don't have control over.